# Decomposing a binary function, into (1) a continuous function and (2) a thresholding function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $f$ is an arbitrary binary function and it is given to us: 
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}
$$
Prove that it is always possible to write this function, as a composition of two functions:

1. A continuous function:  $g: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow (0, 1) $
2. A thresholding function: $h: (0, 1) \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, e.g.  $h(x) = 0.5 + 0.5 sgn(x - 0.5)$

such that: $ \forall X \in \mathbb{R}^d  :  \; \; \;  f(x) = h(g(x))$.

If there is any requirement needed to have such decomposition, please state it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the shareholding function is a function with a single step? That is all values above the threshold are 1 and all values below are 0?

Comment: yeah, I have given an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the threshold is $t$, and that $h(x)=1$ when $x> t$ and $h(x)=0$ when $x\le t$. The other possibility is to have $h(x)=1$ for $x\ge t$ instead, I will deal with this at the end.

If $f=h\circ g$, then $f^{-1}(\{1\})=g^{-1}(h^{-1}(\{1\}))=g^{-1}((t,1))$. Since $g$ is continuous and $(t,1)$ is open, this implies $f^{-1}(1)$ is an open set. This gives a necessary condition for the decomposition to exist; $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ must be open.

This condition is also sufficient. If $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is open, then $C:= f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Let $d:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be defined by
$$
d(x)= \text{dist}(x,C)=\inf_{c\in C}\|x-c\|
$$
Since $C$ is closed, it follows $d(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in C$. Therefore, letting $$g(x)=\frac12 + \frac12\cdot \frac{d(x)}{1+d(x)},$$
then $g(x)=\frac12$ when $x\in C$, while $g(x)>\frac12$ when $x\not\in C$. This means that letting $h(x)=1$ when $x>\frac12$ and $h(x)=0$ when $x\le \frac12$, then $f=h\circ g$.

If you use the other type of threshold function, where $h(x)=1$ for $x\ge t$, then you instead get the necessary condition that $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ must be closed, but otherwise the same logic works. That is, the condition you need is that $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is either open or closed.

Comment: Can one say that, if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it would satisfy such decomposition? (i.e. does Riemann integrablity entail the open/clsoed argument you mentioned?)

Comment: No. For example, let $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & 0\le x <1 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ Then $f$ is Riemann integrable, but $f$ cannot be decomposed the way you want it. Note $f^{-1}(\{1\})=[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: I see that's a good point.

Comment: One more question: does this decomposition always result in a Lipschitz construction? I.e. is it possible to prove that your refined $g(x)$ is Lipschitz? (i.e. has finite derivative).

Comment: Yes, $g(x)$ is always Lipschitz, with constant $1/2$. This follows because $d(x)$ is $1$-Lipschitz, which can be proved using the triangle inequality (exercise left to reader).